# Uter vs. Uterque

Tags: vocabulary, latin-to-english-translation, word-comparison, adjective, cicero

The way I learned 'uter' and 'uterque' was as follows. 'Uter' is like the Greek 'πότερος', meaning (in interrogative uses) 'which, of two?' and (in non-interrogative uses) 'either, of two'. I learned to translate 'uterque' into English as 'both', but is this strictly accurate? When it is said that Cicero uses the method of argumentation 'in utramque partem', this clearly does mean that he argues on *both* sides, but is the more literal translation 'on either side'? If the former is correct, why is 'partem' singular and not plural?

Comment: The word *uter* is typically used interrogatively, whereas *uterque* isn't (cf: the difference between *quis* and *quī*, it's a similar sort of thing here).

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, *uter* is a question word "which [of two]".
And *uterque* can be translated as "both [of two]", but it might be better to think of it as "each [of two]".
The reason is that *uterque*, like "each", is singular.

I think it is clearest to say that *uterque* is "each" and *ambo* is "both".
The meanings overlap significantly, but there are two main differences:

- Grammatically, *uterque* and "each" are singular.
- Semantically, *ambo* or "both" refers to the two being together, whereas *uterque* or "each" means that the two are treated one by one.

When one is arguing both sides of a case, it may be best to do so in turn: first against one party, then the other.
Being against both parties at the same time would be in no party's interests and would look more like arguing against the whole system or something like that.
Therefore *in utramque partem* makes semantically more sense than *in ambas partes*.

When it comes to juridical oratory, arguing *pro aliquo* means defending and arguing *in aliquem* means accusing.
Therefore in an oratory context I would translate *in utramque partem* as "against each party [in turn]".
Translating with "both" is idiomatic English and fine, but I think "each" captures the idea somewhat more accurately.

Comment: llmavirta: Given that "uterque" means "each", what about the plural "utrique" = "both"? Recently, in an anguish-of-indecision over whether to use "ambas" or "utrasque" (fem. acc. plurals) in [Q: "Advice From History"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/11414/79); finally, plumped for the latter. Hoped that suffix-"que" would cover the need for "and" in "and-you-will-lose-both"; but, it's a moot point.

Comment: @tony Pronouns like *quisque* and *uterque* have a specific meaning which cannot be reduced to *quis/uter+que*, and therefore one can't really use *-que* with *quis* or *uter* to mean "and". I would read *utrique* as "each group", for example: *Ille et meae et tuae familiae canit. Utrisque delectat.* That said, I can't recall encountering the plural *utrique* in a text, so a separate question about its plural semantics would be good. (Also note that *utrique* can be a singular dative.)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you are correct, inasmuch as *uter* does indeed mean 'which[of two]?', and *uterque* can be translated as 'both'. The former is interrogative, the second is distributive.

Bear in mind that English has its own ways of expressing this kind of thing: for instance, 'did they both do it?' and 'did each of them do it?' and the replies 'yes, both did it' and 'yes, each of them/each one did it'. 'Both' refers to two acting in unison, while 'each' distributes the responsibility, not necessarily just to two.  The difference from Latin is that in English 'each' is a general distributive, is mostly synonymous with 'either'  and can refer to any number; while in Latin *uterque* is reserved for two.

I might also observe that we tend to be rather sloppy in colloquial English, relying on context to indicate the precise meaning — something that can become irritatingly apparent when translating into Latin.